# Как правильно обертывать элементы?

Tags: html

Всем привет! Недавно задался вопросом "Как правильно обертывать элементы?", знаю что тег  нужно всегда помещать в тег , нужно ли это делать для других html-элементов?, к примеру, для тегов

, .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теги необходимо оборачивать только те элементы, где это необходимо. Семантически обосновано.

Чем меньше у вас вложеность элементоа (тег в теге), тем лучше `html`страница. Что бы понимать что во что можно вкладывать есть [вот такой ресурс](https://caninclude.glitch.me/).

Comment: я не могу понять, а что даёт этот ресурс?

Comment: Проверку. Можешь проверить можно ли `<h2>` оборачивать в тег `<a>`  а наоборот ? и так далие. Ещё можешь воспользоваться для проверки WC3 validator - https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: понял, спасибо!